# Returning An instance of an Object

Tags: c#, object

In my code I was instructed to return an object in my `GetCustomer` method in my `CustomerManager` class from the `Customer` class . I am new to object oriented programming so I don't have any ideas on how to do this. Can someone help me out?

Customer Manager Class

```
public class customerManager
{
    private static int currentCusNo;
    private int maxCustomers;
    private int numCustomers;
    customer[] cList;

    public customerManager(int maxCust, int seed)
    {
        currentCusNo = seed;
        maxCustomers = maxCust;
        numCustomers = 0;
        cList = new customer[maxCustomers];
    }
    public bool addcustomers(string fN, string lN, string ph)
    {
        if (numCustomers > maxCustomers) return false;

        customer m = new customer(fN, lN, ph, currentCusNo);
        currentCusNo++;
        cList[numCustomers] = m;
        numCustomers++;
        return true;

    }
    public int findCustomer(int cusID)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < numCustomers; x++)
        {
            if (cList[x].getID() == cusID)
            {
                return x;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public bool customerExist(int cusID)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < numCustomers; x++)
        {
            if (cList[x].getID() == cusID)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public string customerlist()
    {
        string y = " ";

        for (int x = 0; x < numCustomers; x++)
        {

            y += "\nFirst Name: " + cList[x].getFirstName() + "\nLast name: " + cList[x].getLasttName() + "\nCustomer ID: " + cList[x].getID();

        }

        return y;
    }
    public customer GetCustomer(int cID)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < numCustomers; x++)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Customer Class

```
public class customer
{
    private int customerID;
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;
    private string phone;

    public customer(string fN, string lN, string ph, int cId)
    {
        customerID = cId;
        firstName = fN;
        lastName = lN;
        phone = ph;
    }
    public int getID() { return customerID; }
    public string getFirstName() { return firstName; }
    public string getLasttName() { return lastName; }
    public string getPhone() { return phone; }

    public string toString()
    {
        string s = "";

        s +="First Name: " + firstName + "\nLast Name: " + lastName + "\nPhone: " + phone + "\nCustomer ID: " + customerID;

        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any diference regarding the method you want to implement and the `findCustomer` you already have, since both receive an id. Can you give us more info on what the method should do?

Comment: Copy method `findMethod` rename it to `getCustomer` in loop return `cList[x]`  ad instead of `return false` use `return null`.

Answer (score 3):

When someone says "return an object" in C# they typically mean: "return a reference to the thing I want". Luckily, classes are always stored (at least, for purposes for this discussion) as references already, so this is really simple.

The code will be nearly identical to your `findCustomer` method but instead of returning the index of the customer, it will just return the customer reference.

```
public customer GetCustomer(int cID)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < numCustomers; x++)
    {
        customer testCustomer = cList[x];
        if (testCustomer.getID() == cusID)
        {
            return testCustomer;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I explicitly put the `testCustomer` variable in so that

1. You would see that `cList` is an array of customers and you can pull their references out.
2. Its slightly more efficient to not get the item out of the array twice. If this wasn't constant time the efficiency gain would be more important.

And finally a few helpful hints:

- Classes in C# should be PascalCase (`Customer`)
- Multiple returns should be done with care, as they *can* be confusing to read
- Having manual `get` methods for data is unusual in C#, typically they are just exposed via properties

Comment: The code works just as intended now. Thank so much for the helpful tips and explaining how the code works. I will keep them in mind next time!

Answer (score 0):

Using your code...

Find the index of the cID you want and return the item of the list in this index or null if you do not find.

```
public customer GetCustomer(int cID)
{
    var index = findCustomer(cID);
    return index == -1 ? null : cList[index];
}
```

Or ...

Copy and paste the findCustomer code, changing `return x;` by `return cList[x];` and `-1` to `null`;

```
public customer GetCustomer(int cID)
{
    for (var x = 0; x < numCustomers; x++)
        if (cList[x].getID() == cID)
            return cList[x];
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it would be very similar to your `findCustomer` method, only that instead of returning an `int`, you would return the actual `cutomer` object. If I followed the same pattern of the rest of your class, it would look something like:

```
    public customer GetCustomer(int cID)
    {
       for (int x = 0; x < numCustomers; x++)
       {
          if (cList[x].getID() == cID)
          {
             return cList[x];
          }
       }
       return null;
    }
```

It should be said, however, that if you are using `System.Linq`, then the same method could be done with just one line:

```
    public customer GetCustomer(int cID)
    {
       return cList.Where(x => x.getID() == cID).SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

Cheers
JM

Comment: You do know your code with LINQ doesn't compile? Make sure you review what Where does for the future...

Comment: Instead of Where and First(), you're way better off using Single, or SingleOrDefault in this situation if you don't want the code to break at that moment. No customer should have the same ID, so it'd be better to make the app crash if in the db, there were two customers pointing to the same ID

Comment: Yep. SingleOrDefault makes the most sense. Either give me an exception if there is more than one for some bizaar reason, or give me null.